# Not able to boot VM in virtualbox

Tags: virtualization, boot

I have moved a virtual machine from VMware to VirtualBox and was able to import the virtual drive successfully.

Upon booting the virtual machine, it get stuck on the boot and I am not able to figure out the reason.

[image: Screenshot attached here]

Comment: Detailed information of your migration process and the details of the OS in your VM would help to narrow this down.

Comment: Sorry about that! I exported a Centos7 VM running on VMware workstation as OVF file and imported the vmdk file into the virtualbox.